# Foreach loop a List<T> in C# with random data generation

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

I have a list based of a custom class in C# and I am attempting to use a foreach loop to select each item in the index and using **Random**, randomly generate an **INT** for each item.

However, every item in the foreach loop changes to the same value. Is there away to change this?

this is my custom list:

```
List<patient> p = new List<patient>();
```

this is how i add items to the list:

```
p.Add(new patient(pname, pdob, ploc));
```

and this is the foreach loop in running inside a system.timers event.

```
foreach(patient ps in p)
{
    ps.ploc = new Random().Next(80, 220);
}
```

an example output would be all items have a plocation(ploc) of **120** instead of each item having its own random.

Any solution would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following, you are creating a new random with same seed for every patient, thus getting the same "random" numbers when calling Next()

```
var rnd = new Random();
foreach(patient ps in p)
{
    ps.ploc = rnd.Next(80, 220);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialise the Random outside the foreach

```
Random random = new Random();
foreach(patient ps in p)
{
    ps.ploc = random.Next(80, 220);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you generade a new instance of `Random` in each iteration, using the same seed; consequently the same result is returned in each call. Change the loop the the following code.

```
var iRandom = new Random();
foreach(patient ps in p)
{
    ps.ploc = iRandom.Next(80, 220);
}
```

Comment: My god that was a simple fix. I clearly missed that during googling.

Comment: @rkleman12 You wouldn't guess what stupid mistakes some people (including me) make sometimes...